# KeePass Ubuntu Touch/ Encrypted Password Storage

Tags: ubuntu-touch, keepass

Is there a project under development or is there any solution to be able to use KeePass from Ubuntu Touch?

I could not find anything on the [project web site](http://keepass.info/download.html), so I was wondering If anyone has come across any news regarding this?

Does anyone have any ideas for an alternative that may be used on multiple platforms including Ubuntu Touch? Please share!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of any ongoing development of KeePass (but I don't see why anyone couldn't do it), however I found a couple entries for lastpass in the store you might want to check and see if they suit your needs.

Comment: Lastpass uploads the passwords to somewhere. I was hopingfor  a local solution without storing anything on-line. Still thank you for that lead.